# Why is Britain the only country called "perfidious"?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom

The UK is designated as ***Perfidious Albion***, allegedly, [because of its duplicity in diplomatic affairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfidious_Albion#Origins_and_use) during its imperial times.

Why did only the UK receive this derogatory designation?

Didn't all colonial empires, more or less, apply the same strategies?

Comment: Other countries have been called this.  https://www.nytimes.com/2003/02/09/weekinreview/the-world-character-assassination-the-french-there-is-a-word-for-them.html Perhaps the question is: why has it stuck?

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question to explain why you think the Wikipedia article you cited doesn't answer it?  Admittedly, I didn't spend all that long, but I couldn't find a country that isn't called "perfidious" somewhere online.  Examples include both former colonial powers (e.g. [France](https://www.irishtimes.com/opinion/letters/perfidious-france-1.1104825) ), & former colonies (e.g. both [India](https://www.fairobserver.com/region/central_south_asia/india-perfidious-state/) and [Pakistan](https://spectator.org/perfidious-pakistan/) ).

Comment: (Incidentally, if anyone else wants to repeat that search, I'd advise a degree of caution.  Typing `"perfidious +++++++"` into Google and replacing the `+++++++` with a series of country names returns some very ..  _dubious_  ... sites, whose content definitely does not comply with the SE Code of Conduct!  You have been warned!)

Comment: @sempaiscuba, your examples are irrelevant. Only Britain is authentically called Perfidious. the proof is, other countries don't have articles in Wikipedia.

Comment: As oters have said, many countries have been called perfidious. However the reason, I think, that is associated with England is that when the French called us so, we were rather proud of it. **Look, we must be getting to the xxxxxxx!** When I was at elementary school in the 60's, it was presented in school as though is was a success of British foreign policy.

Comment: @user366312 Then you should probably clarify the wording of your question. And like I suggested in my comment above, it would also help if, while you're at it, you explain why the Wikipedia article you cited doesn't answer it.

Comment: Straight out of left field, but could it be linguistic? *Perfidious Albion* has a lovely metre to it, which *Perfidious France*, *Perfidious Germany* etc lack. The fact that I'm smiling writing this also suggests that, yes, Britons **were** rather proud of it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References to ["Perfidious_Albion"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfidious_Albion) contain references to various hypocrisies of England, (considered as such, by other Europeans).

1) England presumably promoted "progressive" governments, e.g. "Republican" France, then turned around and made alliances with reactionary monarchs, including e.g. the Tsars of Russia. 
2) England preached freedom of religion and suppressed Catholicism in Ireland. 
3) England preached "Take up the White Man's burden," but perpetrated atrocities in India, South Africa, and elsewhere.  
4) England preached "Free trade" but often practiced mercantilism.

Other European countries (e.g. "Republican" France) were either truer to "progressive" ideals that they preached, or else were openly "less Enlightened." For instance, at the Congress of Vienna, the Tsar of Russia stated that he was through with "liberal" ideas.